# why is my 'reverse' string C function not working?

Tags: c, string, char

I'm trying to write a function to reverse the characters in a string in C, but it's not working.

This is what I have:

```
/* ... the  */
char str[1000];
strcpy(&str[0], &text[0]); // get the values from existing 'char text[1000]' 

if (DEBUG) printf("DEBUG: str value before reverse: %s\n", str); 
// reverse the string
reverse(&str[0]);
if (DEBUG) printf("DEBUG: str value after reverse: %s\n", str); 
/* ... */
```

After calling 'reverse', my output looks like this:

```
DEBUG: str value before reverse: this is a line of text
DEBUG: str value after reverse:
```

Here's my function:

```
void reverse(char * str)
{
  char str2[1000];
  int i = 0;
  // find the null in str
  while (str[i] != '\0') {
    i++;
  }
  // now put the chars from str into str2 in the reverse order
  int j = 0;
  while (i >= 0) {
    str2[j] = str[i];
    i--;
    j++;
  }
  str2[j] = '\0';
  // now str2 contains the reverse of str, copy it to str
  strcpy(&str[0], &str2[0]);
  return;
}
```

What's wrong with it?  And is there an easier way to reverse a string?

Comment: Check out the `while (i >= 0)`.

Comment: After your first `while`, `i` is the index of the `'\0'` ending the input, this you place at the beginning of the result. The result will always be an empty string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What's wrong with it?

After the first loop completes, `str[i]` is equal to 0. Therefore the first iteration of the second loop stores the null terminator at the first position of `str2`, making it effectively a string of length 0. Of course it then goes on and writes additional characters to the buffer, but those will be ignored by any function you use.

> And is there an easier way to reverse a string?

Sure. For example, [this implementation](http://www8.cs.umu.se/~isak/snippets/strrev.c) reverses a string in-place without allocating additional buffers:

```
char *strrev(char *str)
{
      char *p1, *p2;

      if (! str || ! *str)
            return str;
      for (p1 = str, p2 = str + strlen(str) - 1; p2 > p1; ++p1, --p2)
      {
            *p1 ^= *p2;
            *p2 ^= *p1;
            *p1 ^= *p2;
      }
      return str;
}
```

Comment: thanks -- you're absolutely right! looks like @CMoi beat you by 6 seconds, tho

Comment: @RobertHume: Actually I beat them by 8 seconds (hover the "answered X time ago" to see timestamps") ;-)

Answer (score 0):

You start copying when str[i] is '\0', so your string will start with it and be empty.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.

After the first while loop, i is the location of the '\0' and I'm making it the first character of str2, so str is always empty string.